# Overloading operator<< for user defined MyList

Tags: c++, list, overloading

**I cannot use std::list**. The goal is to create a user defined MyList that can handle any data type. My problem is with my nested iterator class and possibly my function for overloading operator<<. I have been at this for awhile and I am stuck. Since the deadline is pretty close, I figure that I should risk my neck and ask the question here. It will be great if someone can assist me with this.

I realized that there are memory leaks in my code, but thats not my main concern at the moment.
I also realized that having so many friend function is not a good programming practice, I am planning to use getData() and setData() function to get/set the private variable within node later.

So please overlook the above 2 problems...

Error message:

```
"MyList.h", line 67: Error: iterator is not defined.
```

I'll include the whole header file just so that in case people need to see it. I'll include a comment at line 67 where the error is. Then I'll also include a section of my main function that uses the iterator to show how I am trying to set the iterator and iterate through the list.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstddef>

template<class T>
class Node
{
   friend void MyList<T>::push_front(T aData);
   friend void MyList<T>::push_back(T aData);
   friend void MyList<T>::pop_front();
   friend T MyList<T>::front();
   friend void MyList<T>::print();
   friend MyList<T>::~MyList();
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Node<T>&);
   private:
      T data;
      Node *next;
      Node *prev;
   public:
      Node(T aData);

};

template<class T>
class MyList
{
   Node<T> *head;
   Node<T> *tail;
   public:
      MyList();
      ~MyList();
      void push_front(T aData);
      void push_back(T aData);
      T front();
      void pop_front();
      void operator=(MyList<T>& another_List);

      void print();  //Test function. Delete later.

      class iterator
      {
         private:
            MyList& object;
            Node<T> *current;
         public:
            iterator(MyList<T>&, Node<T>*);     // iterator a(*this, head);
                                                // MyList<int>::iterator a = list.Begin();
            iterator operator++();          // a++
            iterator operator++(int);           // ++a
            iterator operator--();
            bool operator!=(iterator);
            friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, iterator&);
      };

      iterator Begin();
      iterator End();
};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Node<T>& n)
{
   out << *n.current << ' ';

   return out;
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, iterator& i)  //ERROR
{
   out << i->current << ' ';

   return out;
}

template<class T>
Node<T>::Node(T aData)
{
   data = aData;
}

template<class T>
MyList<T>::MyList()
{
   head = NULL;
}

template<class T>
MyList<T>::~MyList()
{
   Node<T> *temp;

   while(head != NULL)
   {
      temp = head;
      head = head->next;
      delete temp;
   }
   head = NULL;
}

template<class T>
void MyList<T>::push_front(T aData)
{
   if(head == NULL)
   {
      head = new Node<T>(aData);
      head->next = tail;
      head->prev = NULL;
      tail->prev = head;
   }
   else
   {
      head->prev = new Node<T>(aData);
      head->prev->prev = NULL;
      head->prev->next = head;
      head = head->prev;
   }
}

template<class T>
void MyList<T>::push_back(T aData)
{
   if(head == NULL)
   {
      head = new Node<T>(aData);
      head->prev = NULL;
      head->next = tail;
      tail->prev = head;
   }
   else
   {
      tail->prev->next = new Node<T>(aData);
      tail->prev->next->prev = tail->prev;
      tail->prev->next->next = tail;
      tail->prev = tail->prev->next;
   }
}

template<class T>
T MyList<T>::front()
{
   return head->data;
}

template<class T>
void MyList<T>::pop_front()
{
   if(head == NULL)
      std::cout << "The List is empty!" << endl;
   else
   {
      head = head->next;
      head->prev = NULL;
   }
}

template<class T>
void MyList<T>::print()
{
   while(head != NULL)
   {
      std::cout << "Test print function" << std::endl;
      std::cout << '[' << head->data << ']' << std::endl;
      head = head->next;
   }
   std::cout << "End of test print function" << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
MyList<T>::iterator::iterator(MyList<T>& list, Node<T>* p)
{
   object = list;
   current = p;
}

template<class T>
typename MyList<T>::iterator MyList<T>::iterator::operator++()
{
   if(current == object.tail)
   {
   }
   else
      current = current->next;
   return this;
}

template<class T>
typename MyList<T>::iterator MyList<T>::iterator::operator++(int)
{
   if(current == object.tail)
   {
   }
   else
      current = current->next;
   return this->prev;
}

template<class T>
typename MyList<T>::iterator MyList<T>::iterator::operator--()
{
   if(current == object.head)
   {
   }
   else
      current = current->prev;
   return this;
}

template<class T>
bool MyList<T>::iterator::operator!=(iterator b)
{
   return (this.current == b.current);
}

template<class T>
typename MyList<T>::iterator MyList<T>::Begin()
{
   return iterator(object, head);
}

template<class T>
typename MyList<T>::iterator MyList<T>::End()
{
   return iterator(object, tail);
}
```

main.cpp

```
   MyList<int>::iterator i = aList.Begin();
   while(i != aList.End())
   {
      cout << i;
      i++;
   }
```

Comment: std::list can handle any data type, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @JonathanPotter because I am not supposed to use std::list. :(

Comment: Presumably you just need to change the definition to `MyList<T>::iterator b` rather than `iterator b` ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I actually tried that, but the error message stays, plus I get an extra warning

Comment: Your `MyList<T>::iterator::operator!=` looks like it's actually computing `MyList<T>::iterator::operator==`.

Comment: You don't initialize `MyList<T>::tail`.

Comment: @Casey Thanks, Casey. But actually the tail is fine. I had a lengthy discussion with a tutor about this. When we push a node into an empty list, that node is set to be the head, the prev pointer is pointing to null and the next pointer is pointing to tail, which is nothing. tail is and always be the node after the last element in the list.

Comment: I don't know what you discussed with your tutor, but I do know that nowhere in this code is `tail` assigned a value, but in many places the value of `tail` is used. Where do you think that value comes from?

Comment: @Casey based on my understanding, which may be completely wrong... since tail pointer is uninitialized, it points to null. tail is used when push_front() or push_back() are called. In push_front(), if the head is null, the list is empty and we set head->next to as tail. In push_back, the same thing happens if the list is empty, else we insert the new node before the tail, and set the new node's next pointer to point at the tail, etc, and then set the new node as tail->prev. Now that i think about it, perhaps I should say that Node<T> *tail = NULL, since I never use tail to do anything?

Comment: If you want it to be `NULL`, you need to initialize it as such. If it will only ever be `NULL`, you should get rid of it and just use a literal `NULL/nullptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the definition of your `iterator` class is nested inside the definition of your `MyList` class template, for all code outside out `MyList`, its name is `MyList<whatever>::iterator`.

Perhaps you intended something slightly different in the code that contains the error though. While you've defined it as a template:

```
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, iterator& i)  //ERROR
{
   out << i->current << ' ';

   return out;
}
```

You don't seem to be using its template parameter (`T`) at all. Perhaps you really intended something more like:

```
template<class iterator>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, iterator& i)  //ERROR
{
   out << i->current << ' ';

   return out;
}
```

In this case you don't need to supply a qualifier, since the `iterator` here is just referring to the template parameter. When you use this, the compiler will normally deduce the type of the iterator you actually pass.

Note that it's unnecessary but somewhat traditional to specify the iterator category in a template parameter like this, so you'd typically use something like `OutIterator` instead of just `iterator` for the template parameter.

This isn't really very generic though -- in particular, the `->current` means it'll only really work for your specific iterator type. More typical code would overload `operator *` for the iterator type, so client code will just dereference the iterator. Also note that iterators are normally assumed to be "lightweight" enough that they're normally passed by value, not by reference.

```
class iterator {
    // ...
    T operator*() { return *current; }
};

// ...
template<class OutIt>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, OutIt i)
{
    out << *i << ' ';
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice the T for some reason.

Comment: However that brought up a new error..
For the function "typename bool MyList<T>::iterator::operator!=(MyList<T>::iterator b)", the compiler produced an error message saying "Error: No direct declarator preceding "("."  It looks okay, so I am not sure what went wrong there.

Comment: @Vince: Your code has a fair number of miscellaneous errors. I haven't tried to go through and show each one and how to fix it (that would be pretty much just writing the code for you). If I were to give a single hint, it would be to nest your `Node` class inside your `MyList` class. No reason for it to be visible to the outside world.

Comment: I realized that. This is a pretty new area for me and things seems to be fine till I tried including a nested iterator class. Then things just went out the window. I appreciate the hint over an actual solution since I need to know this for my exam. Assignment mark is nothing compared to finals mark. Thanks for all the help :)